# Скорость работы PHP скрипта и его отладка

Tags: php

Появилась необходимость собрать базу из 400 тысяч страниц. Написал скрипт для загрузки страниц на локальную машину и дальнейшего скрапинга/парсинга интересующей информации. Быстродействие скрипта неприятно удивило - в среднем на 1 HTML страницу тратится 1 секунда. (Размер страниц 10-40Кб). Код ниже

```
<?php
$limit = 400000; 

for($i = 1; $i <= $limit; $i++) 
{
    $html = file_get_contents('http://Member/Detail/' . $i); 
    $handle = fopen("C:/Server/Parsed_Pages/$i.html", 'a+');
    fwrite($handle, $html);   
    fclose($handle);
}
```

В текущей ситуации, придется ждать около 4 суток пока на локальной машине будет создана копия интересующего каталога.

1) Все ли впорядке со скриптом в плане быстродействия или можно как-то ускорить сбор информации? (Компьютер, на который скачивается база, не самый новый. Как одна из возможных причин неторопливости). Учитывая то, что номера страниц идут по порядку, могу ли я для ускорения запустить несколько скриптов с разных номеров?

2) Как можно отменить выполнение запущенного скрипта? Пока только отключением локального сервера добивался полной отмены выполнения (Ограничение на максимальное время исполнения скрипта стоит в районе недели).

Comment: 1. Попробуйте не сохранять на файл а работать на лету. Без файла. Так ускорится 2 раза. Параллелно можно включать, самое лучщее сделайте так. Что бы не парится. Если у вас 10 параллелных потоков. Каждый поток работает с id = 10*счетчик + поток. Так получится что 1й поток работает с 1,11,21,31,41.... 2. Если первую исправить, отключат не придется. но если нужно сохраняйте обработанные ID на базе

Answer (score 1):

В один поток подгружать страницы очень долго. Нужен curl_multi . Для [примера](https://bitbucket.org/hardworm/provider_parser/src/9755dc4937a91472f819580b6241b87ea6151ab8/providerRSS/intercon_rss.php?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Когда то давно писал парсинг всех новостей провайдеров своего города и генерацию из них rss.

Comment: А есть какие-то ограничения на количество запускаемых параллельно скриптов?